# How do I pass parameters from getBean to a bean created with the @Bean annotation?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, javabeans

Spring has an overload of getBean which accepts parameters.
How can I pass these parameters to a the @Bean creation function for the bean?

```
class Person
{
    String name;
    Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

    public class SpringAnnotationMain {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx =    new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringAnnotationMain.class); 
           Person x = ctx.getBean(Person.class, new Object[] {"Alice"}); 
           System.out.println(x.name);

         ctx.close();
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring will pass the arguments as parameters to the @Bean function, and from there pass it to the constructor of your bean,

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig {
     @Bean
     @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
     Person createPerson(String name)
     {
         return new Person(name);
     }

}
```

Comment: That's a common misconception about Schizophrenia